# python regex carriage return

Tags: python, regex

please could you help with the regex to get everything unto the ";"..

```
window.egfunc = {
  name: "test name",
  type: "test type",
  storeId: "12345"
};
```

I have the following which works when all the data would be on one line, but as soon as there are returns, it won't work...

```
window.egfunc\s+=\s+(.*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the dot with `[\s\S]`:

```
window.egfunc\s+=\s+([\s\S]*?);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot `.` matches everything other than linefeed characters `\n, \r`. As soon as it encounters any LF character, it stops. We will have to explicitly say to regex to use `.` for multi-line using the flags `re.DOTALL`.
Similar modifiers are there in other languages too, like perl has `s` that needs to be added in last.

```
import re

txt = """window.egfunc = {
  name: "test name",
  type: "test type",
  storeId: "12345"
};"""

x = re.findall("window.egfunc\s+=\s+(.*);", txt, re.DOTALL)
print(x)
```

There is one more `re.MULTILINE` or `re.M`, but it didn't work alone. If anyone know the reason, can you please comment out?